# Unable to locate element using ID and xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with locating button.

https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1

I want to add 101 items to basket by using button "Dodaj" to check if alert appears.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button id="add-product-5e9847b5ee071" class="btn btn-sm" role="button" data-add-to-basket="" data-product-price="15.54" data-product-name="Okulary">Dodaj</button>
     </span>
<input type="number" min="0" step="1" class="form-control" value="0" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

I tried to use xpath

```
add = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-product-5e9847b5ee071"]')
```

and also ID "add-product-5e9847b5ee071" but I get message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="add-product-5e9847b5ee071"]"}
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Assuming you're on the correct page, why not try add = self.driver.find_element_by_id("add-product-5e9847b5ee071") Also, given that there is a unique string after add-product-###, maybe make sure that the value doesn't change, and correctly reflects what you want.

Comment: I tried but this also doesn't work. And I wrote it that I also used Id.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="add-product-5e9847b5ee071"]"}

Comment: If the page is refreshed, the alphanumeric string after add-product changes for the button. That is why the element cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the first `Dodaj` button after entering data induce

`WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1")
inputtext=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@class='form-control'])[1]")))
inputtext.clear()
inputtext.send_keys("101")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[text()='Dodaj'])[1]"))).click()
```

---

One more **xpath** option.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1")
inputtext=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h4[text()='Okulary']/following::input[1]")))
inputtext.clear()
inputtext.send_keys("101")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//h4[text()='Okulary']/following::button[1]"))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that while each product Dodaj button has a unique id that changes, they all have the same attribute data-product-name which corresponds to the container. For example, for Piłka, if you want the Dodaj button, you can use the following

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@data-product-name="Piłka"]')
```